# Error in Bash for a Terminal based game (shell scripting)

Tags: shell, syntax-error

I have been working with Debian for a couple of months for school and because it seems really handy to work with. but now I want to make a game for in the terminal. A Higher or Lower card game (also for school but I wanted to make it before I was given this task). You have to pick a Random card and then it asked if you want to bet High or Low. When you choose you bet, it wil created another random card and it wil then check if the new card is higer or lower. I still got a few problems that I can't find myself and hopefully you guys can lead me to the right direction.

The error is my if loops that it cannot find a command, but even after redoing the if loops, it is still the same error. I don't really see what my fault is. In the terminal, it says that my errors ar at line 58,49,97 an 107 and I don't really see my fault or what is wrong.

(if you don't understand a sentence, it is written in dutch)

"Here is the compleet code for the card game:

```
#!/bin/bash
score=0
uitkomst=juist
waardegok=0
echo "Hallo, welkom bij het spel {Hoger of Lager}"
echo "Het doel van het spel is om juist te kunnen gokken..."
echo "...Met kaarten."
echo "Je krijgt een kaart en jij moet gokken of de volgende kaart"
echo "hoger of lager in waarde is."
echo "Als je juist hebt geraden wordt uw juiste gok opgeslagen."
echo "veel succes!!"
echo "Ik ben niet verantwoordelijk voor eventuele verslavingen."

until [ $uitkomst != juist ]
do

Number=$(($RANDOM % 52))

KAARTEN=(Harten1 Harten2 Harten3 Harten4 Harten5 Harten6 Harten7 Harten8
Harten9 Harten10 Harten11 Harten12 Harten13 Klaver1 Klaver2 Klaver3
Klaver4 Klaver5 Klaver6 Klaver7 Klaver8 Klaver9 Klaver10 Klaver11 Klaver12
Klaver13 Schop1 Schop2 Schop3 Schop4 Schop5 Schop6 Schop7 Schop8 Schop9 
Schop10 Schop11 Schop12 Schop13 Ruit1 Ruit2 Ruit3 Ruit4 Ruit5 Ruit6 Ruit7
Ruit8 Ruit9 Ruit10 Ruit11 Ruit12 Ruit13 )


Gokkaart=${KAARTEN[$Number]}
echo " "
echo $Gokkaart
waardekaart=$((Number+1))
echo -n "hoger of lager? type [H of L] > "
read gok
echo "gok: $gok"

if [ "$gok" = "H" ];
then
echo "Uw gok is hoger"
waardegok=54

elif [ "$gok" = "L" ];
then
echo "Uw gok is lager"
waardegok=-1
fi

Number2=$(($RANDOM % 52))

KAARTEN2=(Harten1 Harten2 Harten3 Harten4 Harten5 Harten6 Harten7 Harten8
Harten9 Harten10 Harten11 Harten12 Harten13 Klaver1 Klaver2 Klaver3
Klaver4 Klaver5 Klaver6 Klaver7 Klaver8 Klaver9 Klaver10 Klaver11 Klaver12
Klaver13 Schop1 Schop2 Schop3 Schop4 Schop5 Schop6 Schop7 Schop8 Schop9 
Schop10 Schop11 Schop12 Schop13 Ruit1 Ruit2 Ruit3 Ruit4 Ruit5 Ruit6 Ruit7
Ruit8 Ruit9 Ruit10 Ruit11 Ruit12 Ruit13 )

Gokkaart2=${KAARTEN2[$Number2]}
waardekaart2=$((Number2+1))

if [$Number2 -ge 0 ] && [ $Number2 -le 12 ];
then
echo "De volgende kaart is een harten, namelijk $Gokkaart2"
if [ $waardegok -gt $waardekaart2 ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
elif [ $waardegok -lt $waardekaart2 ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
else
echo "fout, goed geprobeerd"
uitkomst=false
fi


elif [ $Number2 -ge 13 ] && [ $Number2 -le 25 ];
then
echo "De volgende kaart is een klaver, namelijk $Gokkaart2"
if [ $waardegok -gt $waardekaart2 ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
elif [ $waardegok -lt $waardekaart2 ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
else
echo "fout, goed geprobeerd"
uitkomst=false
fi

elif [ $Number2 -ge 26 ] &&  [ $Number2 -le 38 ];
then
echo "De volgende kaart is een Schoppen, namelijk $Gokkaart2"
if [ $waardegok -gt $waardekaart2 ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
elif [ $waardegok  -lt  $waardekaart2 ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
else
echo "fout, goed geprobeerd"
uitkomst=false
fi

elif [ $Number2 -ge 39 ] && [ $Number2 -le 52 ];
then
echo "De volgende kaart is een Ruiten, namelijk $Gokkaart2"
if [ $waardegok -gt $waardekaart2 ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
elif [ $waardegok -lt $waardekaart2 ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
else
echo "fout, goed geprobeerd"
uitkomst=false
fi
fi
done
echo " uw score is $score"
```

Comment: Ok, I made some modification and now I am still stuck with one problem. I want to check the previous value but and also check If my gues is right. But it still doesn't do it the way I want to, it doesn't compare the 2 different card to each other.

if [ "$score" -ge 1 ];
then
Number=$(($RANDOM % 52))
Gokkaart=${KAARTEN[$Number]}
oldNumber=$Number
echo "De kaart is $Gokkaart2"

elif [ "$score" -eq 0 ];
then
echo "Laten we beginnen"

fi

Comment: and also 

if [ "$Number2" -ge 0 ] && [ "$Number2" -le 12 ];
then
echo "De volgende kaart is een harten, namelijk $Gokkaart2"
if [ $waardegok -gt $waardekaart2 ] && [ "$oldNumber -gt $Number2" ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
echo "uw score is nu $score"
echo " "
elif [ $waardegok -lt $waardekaart2 ] && [ "$oldNumber -lt $Number2" ];
then
echo "goed gegokt"
score=$((score+1))
echo "uw score is nu $score"
echo " "
else
echo "fout, goed geprobeert"
uitkomst=false
fi

With this I compare the old and new card and the quess and for al 4 types but stil doesn't work